# Why can I break vim user-function naming rule by using a pound sign (#)

Tags: vim

The vimscript help files state that when defining a user function:

> The function name must start with an uppercase letter, to avoid
>   confusion with builtin functions.

This is enforced except in the following cases that I discovered by looking at other's code.

```
"This should not work.
"But it does as long as the function is in a file called 'overrides.vim'.
function! overrides#name() abort
  echo 'Test overrides\name'
endfunction

"This should not work either.
"But it does as long as the file above is in a folder called 'plugin'.
function! plugin#overrides#name() abort 
  echo 'Test plugin\overrides\name'
endfunction

let stupid = {}
"This should not work.
"But it does aslong as the stupid Dictionary is defined.
function! stupid.name() abort
  echo 'Test stupidname'
endfunction


call overrides#name()
call plugin#overrides#name()
call stupid.name()
```

I looked everywhere for anything that would explain this syntax. I know this works now.  What I am very curious about is, for those of you have used this syntax, where did you learn about it?

Are there other vimscript functionality that are not mentioned anywhere in the help files?

Comment: Since builtin functions won't contain the `#` character, there is no possibility of confusion so the rule about starting function names with a capital letter doesn't apply for autloaded functions.

Comment: @qqx That can't be it because I can name a function `crazy&name` or `crazy*name` and the script will fail with `E128: Function name must start with a capital or contain a colon."

Comment: @dkinzer It only says that parser first uses something dump to determine where function name ends and then starts the checking. If you fix it (`Crazy&name`) you will get different error which still does not say `&` is not allowed in function name: `E124: Missing '(': Crazy&name()`. There is more information: `fu <snr>abc()` works, just as well as `fu <snr>:()` and `fu a:::::::::::b()`. But unlike autoload and dictionary functions this is not mentioned anywhere in help.

Comment: And unlike `&` and `*` characters `#` has no other meaning and can’t be possibly confused with (part) of some operator.

Comment: @ZyX I had kind of deduced the `:` stuff as name spacing.  `function! my:namespace:name()` works too.

Comment: Nope. It looks like a parser bug that exists for allowing `s:` functions. Don’t use it for something else as it is not documented, “namespacing” is normally done by `my#namespace#name()` (with putting into separate files in `autoload/` directory), dictionaries can also be used for the same job.

Comment: If you deadly need to allow changing namespace prefix the only option you are left with is dictionaries. Plugins built on top of [my frawor framework](https://bitbucket.org/ZyX_I/frawor) are an edge case: most of them contain no non-dictionary functions at all (excluding `s:Eval` defined always for technical reasons, but used only once). (Though the only plugins built on top of it I saw are my own ones.) It solves namespacing problems perfectly: as far as two plugins that define feature or post resource with the same name are not in the dependency list of one other plugin no problems occur.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This naming syntax is for `autoload` function. Type `:help autoload-functions` for help.

```
AUTOMATICALLY LOADING FUNCTIONS ~
                                                          *autoload-functions*
When using many or large functions, it's possible to automatically define them
only when they are used.  There are two methods: with an autocommand and with
the "autoload" directory in 'runtimepath'.
```

Comment: Graat and :help Dictionary-functions answered the second part of my question.  It's all in there after all.